# Cambio genere al plurale, quali origini?

Tags: etymology, gender, plural, grammatical-number

Alcune parole cambiano genere al plurale. Che io sappia sono tutte parti del corpo:

- dito/a
- braccio/a
- orecchio/e
- ginocchio/a
- (soprac)ciglio/a

(mi pare questa sia la lista completa, se ne esistono altre aggiungete pure nei commenti)

Mi domandavo: che storia etimologica c'è dietro? 
Come si sono venute a formare queste coppie singolare maschile/plurale femminile?
Se la lista è completa, c'è qualche motivo per cui è successo solo con parti del corpo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ciò dipende principalmente da una reinterpretazione al femminile dell'originale neutro plurale dei nomi latini di seconda declinazione. Questi nomi sono detti in italiano *nomi sovrabbondanti* ([1](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-ambigeneri_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/)).

In latino i nomi neutri di seconda declinazione **al nominativo** singolare hanno desinenza in "*-um*" (come i nomi di seconda declinazione non neutri) mentre al plurale hanno desinenza in "*-a*" (come i nomi di prima declinazione). I nomi latini di prima declinazione in italiano sono normalmente diventati nomi femminili terminanti in "*-a*"; i nomi di seconda declinazione sono normalmente diventati nomi maschili terminanti in "*-o*", con tantissime eccezioni, ovviamente. Da qui la reinterpretazione di cui si diceva su.

Di plurali irregolari ce ne sono a bizzeffe. Qualche altro esempio lo trovi [qui](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurali_irregolari#Plurali_con_cambio_di_genere), ai plurali con cambio di genere e ai plurali dei nomi sovrabbondanti. Come vedi non sono solo parti del corpo.

Da notare che ci sono anche casi di nomi femminili al singolare e plurali al maschile, come *la eco*, *gli echi*.

Comment: Non so se è chiaro dalla risposta che “nomi sovrabbondanti”, in senso proprio, si dice delle parole che ammettono un doppio plurale, quello basato sul plurale neutro e quello “regolare” (braccia/bracci, mura/muri, budella/budelli, urli/urla), o lo ammettevano in passato e ora se ne usa uno solo. Nota in particolare che i plurali “neutri” non si hanno solo per parti del corpo, e che quando sopravvivono entrambi i plurali spesso quello “neutro” si riferisce a insiemi generici, quasi informi (grida, lenzuola, budella), mentre quello maschile a più di un oggetto, ognuno dei quali ben distinto.